# tinyXML lib cannot read ‘&’ properly

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have an XML file with some lines like the following:

```
<rule pat="&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&(?<B>B) ?(?<AND>&) ?(?<E>E)">
```

I use TinyXML lib in C++ to parse this XML file, but when I try to get the 'pat' attribute of such lines, the TinyXML turns out just ignore any occurrence of character `&`. That is, the result read by TinyXML turns to be like:

```
(?<B>B) ?(?<AND>) ?(?<E>E)
```

with all `&` missing!

This char is a part of my regular expression pattern, so this will lead to further error in my program.

Do anyone have any idea why this character `&` is so **SPECIAL** and TinyXML just cannot read? even a stand alone `&` will be dismissed?

Comment: `&` in XML is encoded as `&amp;`. [XML Basics](http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html)

Comment: In other words, your premise is wrong. You don't have an XML file, you have a non-XML file. Find out who produced it and tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because that is not a *valid* XML file. You can't just stick an `&` character anywhere in XML. You have to escape it with entities:

```
&amp;
```

TinyXML will only read valid XML files (or at least mostly valid ones).

Similarly, you need to escape the `<` and `>` characters too, with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not well formed XML.  If you want an `&` character, you need to put `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

In `xml`, `&` is represented as `&amp;`